# Convert Detectron2 model to torchscript

Tags: python, machine-learning, detectron, torchscript

i want to convert detectron2 'COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml model' to torchscript.
I used torc
my code are given below.

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

import torch
from detectron2 import model_zoo
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor
from detectron2.modeling import build_model
from detectron2.export.flatten import TracingAdapter
import os

ModelPath='/home/jayasanka/working_files/create_torchsript/model.pt'
with open('savepic.npy', 'rb') as f:
    image = np.load(f)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml"))

cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 1  # your number of classes + 1

cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = os.path.join(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, ModelPath)

cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.60  # set the testing threshold for this model

predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)
```

i used TracingAdapter and trace functions.i hvent much idea whats the concept behind that.

```
# im = cv2.imread(image)
im = torch.tensor(image)

def inference_func(model, image):
    inputs= [{"image": image}]
    return model.inference(inputs, do_postprocess=False)[0]

wrapper= TracingAdapter(predictor, im, inference_func)
wrapper.eval()
traced_script_module= torch.jit.trace(wrapper, (im,))
traced_script_module.save("torchscript.pt")
```

it gives error given below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 49, in <module>
    traced_script_module= torch.jit.trace(wrapper, (im,))
  File "/home/jayasanka/anaconda3/envs/vha/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/jit/_trace.py", line 744, in trace
    _module_class,
  File "/home/jayasanka/anaconda3/envs/vha/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/jit/_trace.py", line 959, in trace_module
    argument_names,
  File "/home/jayasanka/anaconda3/envs/vha/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jayasanka/anaconda3/envs/vha/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1039, in _slow_forward
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jayasanka/anaconda3/envs/vha/lib/python3.7/site-packages/detectron2/export/flatten.py", line 294, in forward
    outputs = self.inference_func(self.model, *inputs_orig_format)
  File "script.py", line 44, in inference_func
    return model.inference(inputs, do_postprocess=False)[0]
  File "/home/jayasanka/anaconda3/envs/vha/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yacs/config.py", line 141, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: inference
```

can you help me to figure out this.
is there any other methods to do that easily?

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
def inference(model, inputs):
    # use do_postprocess=False so it returns ROI mask
    inst = model.inference(inputs, do_postprocess=False)[0]
    return [{"instances": inst}]

isinstance(image, np.ndarray) == True
image_tensor = torch.as_tensor(image.astype("float32").transpose(2, 0, 1))
wrapper= TracingAdapter(predictor, inputs=[{"image": image_tensor}], inference_func=inference)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at your `inference_func()`:

```
# im = cv2.imread(image)
im = torch.tensor(image)

def inference_func(model, image):
    inputs= [{"image": image}]
    return model.inference(inputs, do_postprocess=False)[0]

wrapper= TracingAdapter(predictor, im, inference_func)
wrapper.eval()
traced_script_module= torch.jit.trace(wrapper, (im,))
traced_script_module.save("torchscript.pt")
```

the function return `model.inference()` and in your `TracingAdapter(predictor, im, inference_func)`, you are passing a predictor instead of the model. To correct this error:

1. Import the DetectionCheckpointer

```
from detectron2.checkpoint import DetectionCheckpointer
```

2. Build the model using buildmodel and load the weights with the help of DetectionCheckpointer
3. Now finally in TracingAdapter replace *predictor* with *model* variable.

Full code below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torch
from detectron2 import model_zoo
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor
from detectron2.modeling import build_model
from detectron2.export.flatten import TracingAdapter
import os
from detectron2.checkpoint import DetectionCheckpointer

ModelPath='/home/jayasanka/working_files/create_torchsript/model.pt'
with open('savepic.npy', 'rb') as f:
    image = np.load(f)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml"))

cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 1  # your number of classes + 1

cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = os.path.join(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, ModelPath)

cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.60  # set the testing threshold for this model

# predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)
model = build_model(cfg)
DetectionCheckpointer(original_model).load(cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS)

im = torch.tensor(image)

def inference_func(model, image):
    inputs= [{"image": image}]
    return model.inference(inputs, do_postprocess=False)[0]

wrapper= TracingAdapter(model, im, inference_func)
wrapper.eval()
traced_script_module= torch.jit.trace(wrapper, (im,))
traced_script_module.save("torchscript.pt")
```